# How to extract the buildings bottom surfaces from a large city 3D mesh?

Tags: graphs, computer-graphics

I have a 3D mesh comprised of city buildings, no ground surface, just buildings.
The goal is to extract the buildings bottom surfaces.
So far I have tried to cut the mesh by a threshold computed from the vertices height histogram - it works good for relatively flat areas, but fails badly for areas with uneven ground level. Now I'm looking towards some approach based on graph algorithms, but nothing concrete so far. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your input? Do you have a cloud of points and try to detect bottom? Does this mesh got any pointers about what points represent what?

Comment: @Evil Input is one big mesh in FBX format - polygons, edges, vertices, that is all. Z axis is pointing up.